# Get Full HTML response from an API call with HTML +JS response

Tags: javascript, java, android, html

I´m trying to connect with an endpoint, but response is incomplete, because part of the html is on js. I'm working on Android Studio with Java. How can I get full HTML on the response of the API request?

**Request on Postman:**

GET: https://tienda.mercadona.es/search-results?query=aceite

**Response:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    ...

<body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <div id="modal-info"></div>
    <script>
        !function(e){function r(r){for(var n,l,f=r[0],i=r[1],a=r[2],c=0,s=[];c<f.length;c++)l=f[c],Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o,l)&&o[l]&&s.push(o[l][0]),o[l]=0;for(n in i)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(i,n)&&(e[n]=i[n]);for(p&&p(r);s.length;)s.shift()();return u.push.apply(u,a||[]),t()}function t(){for(var e,r=0;r<u.length;r++){for(var t=u[r],n=!0,f=1;f<t.length;f++){var i=t[f];0!==o[i]&&(n=!1)}n&&(u.splice(r--,1),e=l(l.s=t[0]))}return e}var n={},o={1:0},u=[];function l(r){if(n[r])return n[r].exports;var t=n[r]={i:r,l:!1,exports:{}};return e[r].call(t.exports,t,t.exports,l),t.l=!0,t.exports}l.m=e,l.c=n,l.d=function(e,r,t){l.o(e,r)||Object.defineProperty(e,r,{enumerable:!0,get:t})},l.r=function(e){"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})},l.t=function(e,r){if(1&r&&(e=l(e)),8&r)return e;if(4&r&&"object"==typeof e&&e&&e.__esModule)return e;var t=Object.create(null);if(l.r(t),Object.defineProperty(t,"default",{enumerable:!0,value:e}),2&r&&"string"!=typeof e)for(var n in e)l.d(t,n,function(r){return e[r]}.bind(null,n));return t},l.n=function(e){var r=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e.default}:function(){return e};return l.d(r,"a",r),r},l.o=function(e,r){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,r)},l.p="/";var f=window.webpackJsonp=window.webpackJsonp||[],i=f.push.bind(f);f.push=r,f=f.slice();for(var a=0;a<f.length;a++)r(f[a]);var p=i;t()}([])
    </script>
    <script src="/v616/static/js/2.2a3d3a37.chunk.js"></script>
    <script src="/v616/static/js/main.e428a20b.chunk.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

[Postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKYHH.png)

**Full HTML from webpage directly:**

```
<head>
...
</head>
<body class="">
<noscript>
You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
<div id="root">
<div class="cookie-banner">
<img class="cookie-banner__image" alt="cookie" src="data:image/png;base64,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">
<div>
<p class="cookie-banner__disclaimer footnote1-r">
Utilizamos cookies propias y de terceros, de sesión y persistentes, con la finalidad de hacer que la navegación de los usuarios por nuestra página web sea fácil y segura. A su vez, utilizamos cookies para medir y obtener datos estadísticos de la navegación de los usuarios. Puedes configurar y aceptar el uso de cookies, así como modificar tus opciones de consentimiento en cualquier momento.<a class="cookie-banner__info" target="_blank" href="/legal/cookies/es/" rel="noopener noreferrer">
Más información</a>
</p>
<div class="cookie-banner__actions">
<a class="cookie-banner__info" target="_blank" href="/legal/cookies/es/" rel="noopener noreferrer">
Más información</a>
<button type="button" class="ui-button ui-button--small ui-button--secondary ui-button--positive">
Configuración</button>
<button type="button" class="ui-button ui-button--small ui-button--primary ui-button--positive">
Aceptar todas</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="snack-bars">
</div>
<header role="banner" class="header">
<div class="header__left">
<button class="logo" aria-label="Home">
</button>
<div class="search" role="search" aria-label="Buscar productos">

...
```

[Webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFjXO.png)

Comment: Please include the code you're using to fetch the page

Comment: To fetch the page (with full html), im using only inspector though chrome